# C++ check for specific number of input

Tags: c++, string, input

I have a function that prompts the user for input. If they input more than the number of words I want(3), then an error should be printed. How do I approach this? I found out how to check if the input is < 3, but not > 3.

```
struct Info
{
  std::string cmd;
  std::string name;
  std::string location;
}

Info* get_string()
{
  std::string raw_input;
  std::getline(std::cin, raw_input);
  std::istringstream input(raw_input);

  std::string cmd;
  std::string name;
  std::string location;

  input>>cmd;
  input>>name;
  input>>location;

  Info* inputs = new Info{cmd, name, location};

  return inputs;
}
```

The function I have automatically takes 3 strings and stores them in my struct, which I check later to see if any part of the struct is empty (for example: "Run" "Joe" ""), but what if they enter in 4 strings? Thank you

Comment: Whether the fourth string should be ignored or not is debatable and not asked here. I don't understand the downvotes. Hint for the question: attempt to read a fourth string and expect it to fail (e.g. being empty)!

Comment: I guess people think it's a stupid question when I'm new at programming and am looking for better ways to code. Anyways, I was thinking about looking at the 4th, but how would I do that in my case? Would I have to create another element in my struct to represent the 4th string?

Comment: No, you only need a forth local `std::string` variable in your `get_string` function: `std::string remainder; input << remainder; if (!remainder.empty()) { /* user has given a forth word */ }`.  It does not make sense to copy that data you are not even interested in into your `Info` struct.

Answer (score 0):

you can split the input string into words with a space delimiter and then check the number of words. you can use the function below to split your input. after this you can check the size of the vector.

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;

vector<std::string> split(const string &s, char delim) {
    stringstream ss(s);
    string item;
    vector<string> res;
    while (getline(ss, item, delim)) {
        if(item.length()==0)continue;
        res.push_back(item);
    }
    return res;
}
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{

    string theString;
    cin>>theString;
    vector<string> res=split(theString, ' ');
    if(res.size()>3)
    {
        //show error
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is a bit excessive. Aside from having a high overhead by creating multiple vectors, another stream, and a string, you only need to look at the last word. The `>>` operator is the best way to get things where they need to go if split by a space, so why scan the entire string if you can just scan the last one.

Comment: you could use strtok to split the string. this would be faster. it still looks better to me than using >> n times.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with this and with Ferdinand's idea is that in order to test if a 4th string exists, you have to "ask" for it. If it exists, you can error, but if it doesn't then it sits there waiting for input and the user wonders what is going wrong.

Thus I'm going to modify your code slightly. It's fairly straight forward. If the user enters a space in the last "word", then you know that there is an issue and can deal with it as you wish.

```
// Replace input >> location; with the below
// Get until the line break, including spaces
getline(input, location);

// Check if there is a space (I.e. 2+ words)
if(location.find(" ") != string::npos){
    // If so, fail
}
```

Resources for learning:

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/find/
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/getline/

Comment: You are missing a detail: In the question's example, user input is read into a variable, `std::istringstream input`, and the content of this variable is then split.  Trying to read a forth string will not block the program and wait for user input.